# React native crashes with SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'key' but only on iOS < 10

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

My React Native project works fine on iOS 10 but crashes on iOS 8 and 9, with `SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'key'`. There's no obvious place where `'key'` is defined twice, and moreover I removed all the keys from my sources but the error persists.

What I'm looking for is a way to find this needle in my haystack, as ESLint with the react-native plugin only finds style issues in my .js files.

Answer (score 0):

[jsx-no-duplicate-props](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-duplicate-props.md) is what you are looking for I guess.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! But my code isn't the problem, as this doesn't happen on iOS 10.